# Is calling `close()` redundant if file opened with `with` statement

Tags: python

Assume I have the following code:

```
with open('somefile.txt') as my_file:
    # some processing
    my_file.close()
```

Is `my_file.close()` above redundant?

Comment: generally using with unmanaged resources. (Socket, SQL connection etc.) And also "with" close automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is; Beside, it is not guarranty that your `close()` will always be executed. (for instance if an `Exception` occurs).

```
with open('somefile.txt') as my_file:
    1/0 # raise Exception
    my_file.close() # Your close() call is never going to be called
```

But the `__exit__()` function of the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement is **always** executed because it follows the `try...except...finally` pattern.

> The with statement is used to wrap the execution of a block with
>   methods defined by a context manager (see section With Statement
>   Context Managers). This allows common try...except...finally usage
>   patterns to be encapsulated for convenient reuse.
>
> The context manager’s __exit__() method is invoked. If an exception
>   caused the suite to be exited, its type, value, and traceback are
>   passed as arguments to __exit__()

You can check that the file have been close right after the `with` statement using `closed`

```
>>> with open('somefile.txt') as f:
...     pass
>>> f.closed
# True
```

Source for my answer:

- [Understanding Python's "with" statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Exiting the `with` block will close the file.

However, that is not necessarily true for objects that are not files. Normally, exiting the context should trigger an operation conceptually equivalent to "close", but in fact `__exit__` can be overloaded to execute any code the object wishes.

Answer (score 1):

The `with` statement creates a runtime context.Python creates the stream object of the `file` and tells it that it is entering a runtime context. When the with code block is completed, Python tells the stream object that it is exiting the runtime context,and the stream object calls its own close() method.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the with statement takes care of that

as you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement):

> The context manager’s `__exit__()` method is invoked. If an exception caused the suite to be exited, its type, value, and traceback are passed as arguments to `__exit__()`.

In the case of files, the `__exit__()` method will close the file